# Regex that allows one letter

Tags: regex

I'm looking for regex extract that would pull what I need from the following strings please:

2/A 100 House
to result in :      2/A 100

7/X 7 Capital Flat
to result in :      7/X 7

0/H 98 Kale Road
to result in :      0/H 98

The numbers and letter after the / can be anything so needing something more generic.  I'm not too familiar with regex and I've only managed to extract everything before first occurrence of a letter using (.*?)\[A-Za-z]

I need to keep the first occurence of a letter and the following space and number but want rid of every other letter after that.

I'm coding in SQL.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Please provide explicit example of what you want to capture from different strings.

Comment: You're trying to get the number or letters after /. But there're two /. Which one? Both? Please give an example of what you expect to get from the string after the regex?

Comment: Added further examples to main post. Original to desired result. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Can you give an example? Like an example of what you want to get from `2/A 100 House to 2/A 100`

Comment: Sorry I'm not being clear, it's 'original' to 'result'. So the House would be dropped. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your example, I'm assuming both the first character and the last one before the text you want to remove will be a digits. And the first character after / will be a letter

```regex
\d+\/\w+\s+\d+
```

---

**See demo:** https://regex101.com/r/cLGvkm/1

Comment: This is doing exactly what I need. Thank you!!